# MariaDB installation problem 'mariadb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.'

Tags: database, ubuntu, mariadb

I'm trying to reinstall MariaDB and I can't figure why the installation fails. I had MySQL installed previously and wanted to get MariaDB for versioning problems so if you guys can help, thank you.
Here are some commands I did on my shell and the results.
Really sorry about my shell being in French, hope you guys can help me anyway.
Between, I have a Ubuntu 20.04tls OS.

```
> sudo apt autoremove --purge ~n^mysql-server

> sudo apt install mariadb-server
```

> ● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.31 database server
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
> Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Mon 2021-11-01 20:38:21 CET; 2min 1s ago
> Docs: man:mysqld(8)
> https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
> Process: 979 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER > > $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
> Main PID: 979 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

> nov. 01 20:38:19 zemmouri-Inspiron-15-3567 mysqld[979]: 2021-11-01 20:38:19 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events

> nov. 01 20:38:19 zemmouri-Inspiron-15-3567 mysqld[979]: 2021-11-01 20:38:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.

> nov. 01 20:38:19 zemmouri-Inspiron-15-3567 mysqld[979]: 2021-11-01 20:38:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...

> nov. 01 20:38:19 zemmouri-Inspiron-15-3567 mysqld[979]: 2021-11-01 20:38:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buff>

> nov. 01 20:38:19 zemmouri-Inspiron-15-3567 mysqld[979]: 2021-11-01 20:38:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 211101 20:38:19

> nov. 01 20:38:21 zemmouri-Inspiron-15-3567 mysqld[979]: 2021-11-01 20:38:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"

> nov. 01 20:38:21 zemmouri-Inspiron-15-3567 mysqld[979]: 2021-11-01 20:38:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1625461;>

> nov. 01 20:38:21 zemmouri-Inspiron-15-3567 mysqld[979]: 2021-11-01 20:38:21 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

> nov. 01 20:38:21 zemmouri-Inspiron-15-3567 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.

> nov. 01 20:38:21 zemmouri-Inspiron-15-3567 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.31 database server.

And it fails on the installation menu:
on the installation menu waiting for like 2 or 3 minutes then it shows this:
`Job for mariadb.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.`

`See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

`Paramètre de mariadb-server (1:10.3.31-00ubuntu0.20.04.1)...`

`Traitement des actions différées (<< triggers >>) pour systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.13)...`

`Traitement des actions différées (<< triggers >>) pour man-db (2.9.1-1)`

`Traitement des actions différées (<< triggers >>) pour libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2)...`

Comment: After removing `mysql-server` you should make sue no left over config files (like `my.cnf`) do exist.

Comment: Hi, @Luuk i'all try to edit the question, sorry i was absent this week. and to answer your first question, i was going from mysql-server and mysql-client 8.0 to mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.31-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Comment: @Luuk it always stops in this pattern when trying to create symlinks: `Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service → /lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service → /lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mariadb.service → /lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service.`

Comment: My [spy glass](https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=435407) does not show WHY that fails, please [edit] the question, and show the complete log that shows this failing step.

Comment: @Luuk on the previous  comment i showed you where it fails, it stack on the installation menu waiting for like 2 or 3 minutes then it shows this: `Job for mariadb.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
Paramètre de mariadb-server (1:10.3.31-00ubuntu0.20.04.1)...
Traitement des actions différées (<< triggers >>) pour systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.13)...
Traitement des actions différées (<< triggers >>) pour man-db (2.9.1-1)
Traitement des actions différées (<< triggers >>) pour libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2)...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some reachers i had a problem with the Symlinks that has been created from mysql-server installation so:

I fixed the problem with running:

> sudo systemctl disable mysql.service

Then:

> sudo apt autoremove --purge mysql-server* mariadb-server*

and finnaly:

> sudo apt update

and after that just run lamp installation with this command and worked perfectly:

> sudo apt install apache2 php libapache2-mod-php mariadb-server php-mysql

Comment: To me it still leads to a timeout error after creating the symlinks. Even disabling `mysql.service` :(

Answer (score 1):

1. Uninstall apparmor and, remove directory /etc/apparmor/ and /etc/apparmor.d/
2. Reboot
3. Install apparmor